# Mark a Field as IsRequired having attribute [XmlElement]

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xml-serialization

I have a class that I want to serialize

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://xyz.com/schema")]
public class Customer
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
    public string Url{ get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)]
    public string Count { get; set; }
}
```

When deserializing if Url is null then the out XML does not contain Url Node. 
How can mark it as a required field so that Url node gets created everytime?

Comment: Why don't you use `using System.Xml.Serialization;` and drop all the namespace prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsNullable` attribute should do it.

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2,IsNullable=true)]
```

If its set to true, it should generate the tag (According to MSDN).

> If the `IsNullable` property is set to true, the `xsi:nil` attribute is
>   generated for class members that have been set to a null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic). For example if you set a field named
>   `MyStringArray` to a `null` reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), the
>   XmlSerializer generates the following XML code.

```
<MyStringArray xsi:nil = "true" />
```